# Programa Java que dada la edad de una persona muestre un mensaje indicando si es mayor de edad NO se puede utilizar ninguna sentencia condicional

Tags: java

tengo que diseñar un programa como indico en el título.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("¿Cuál es tú edad?:");
    int edad = Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
    if (edad>18)
    {
        System.out.print("Eres mayor de edad");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Eres menor de edad");
        
    }
}
```

Todo bien hasta el momento que me he dado cuenta que no puedo utilizar ninguna sentencia condicional.

Al ser principiante me he quedado un poco estancado en este código, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias!

Comment: Dependiendo de qué se entienda por sentencia condicional, podrías usar un operador ternario: `print("Eres " +(edad > 18 ? "mayor ":"menor ") + "de edad");`

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. Por sentencia condicional, entiendo que es "if" "else" "elseif"

Answer (score 0):

Déjame decirte que es un ejercicio extremadamente irreal e inútil, pero en aras del aprendizaje que alguien pudiera tener, una forma de que tu código no tenga condicionales como:

- operador ternario
- if
- switchs
- ciclos
- metodos que refresen un booleano

y otras cosas obvias que se le pudiera ocurrir a alguien que hace ejercicios para programación competitiva; y en que puedas demostrar que tienes mas formas que las mas intuitivas, simples, lógicas y practicas de resolver un problema que nunca sucederá en la vida real puedes usar programación funcional, esta fue integrada en Java SE desde el ya obsoletísimo java 8 con algo tipo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("¿Cuál es tú edad?:");
    Optional<Integer> edad = Optional.ofNullable(Integer.valueOf(teclado.nextLine()));
    Predicate<Integer> pruebaMenorDeEdad = i -> (i < 18);
    String cadena = edad.filter(laEdad -> pruebaMenorDeEdad.test(laEdad))
            .map((x) -> "Eres menor de edad") // x se ignora porque ya sabemos que si se cumple el predicado es un menor de edad
            .orElse("Eres mayor de edad");

    System.out.println(cadena);
}
```

Aqui podemos ver el uso de `Optional` que es una semi-monada que te permite empezar a usar apis mas funcionales sobre tus datos comunes ( basicamente una envoltura ).
Los predicados que son funciones lambda que cumplen una interfaz funcional que contiene le metodo test y que regresan un... valor booleano.
`filter` nos permite en el caso de `Optional` regresar el elemento interno si cumple la condicion o un `Optional.empty` en caso de que no.
Usando la funcion `map` encadenada basicamente transformamos usando una funcion, y con el `orElse` en caso de tener un Optional.empty en cualqueir parte de la cadena de llamadas regresamos un valor por defecto.

Puedes leer mas acerca de optional en la [documentacion oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Solo me queda decir que en realidad esta es otra trampa, ya que si revisamos como esta el codigo del metodo filter:

```
public Optional<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    if (!isPresent()) {
        return this;
    } else {
        return predicate.test(value) ? this : empty();
    }
}
```

hay un `if`... y no se que implementación se use en tiempo de ejecución para `Predicate` pero te aseguro que también internamente tiene un `if`